# Webpack pass a variable into the start/build script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a React app which is built inside a Docker container when deployed. It all works as it should, no issues. I have an .env file for development with an `API_URL` variable and an .env.prod file for deployment with a different `API_URL`. The .env files get passed directly inside the start/build scripts, like this (for `yarn start`):

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development env-cmd .env node server"
```

So, the `API_URL` variable is inside the .env file used in this script. My question is - can I somehow pass the variable to `yarn start` or `yarn build`? When I tried, for testing, adding the variable directly in the script, it didn't get picked up, like so: `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development API_URL="my api url" env-cmd .env node server"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is correct except that [`env_cmd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) is overriding that key.

You should use the `--no-override` flag so it won't.

The final line should like: `API_URL="my api url" env_cmd .env --no-override node server"`

Comment: This sounds like a solution to half of my problem - I still need a way to pass the variable directly from the terminal. Pseudocode: `yarn start VARIABLE=value`. So if I add `--no-override` to the script itself inside package.json, can I somehow pass the variable from the terminal?

Comment: I tried: `cross-env VARIABLE=value yarn start` but it didn't get picked up

Comment: I forgot to add the new variable to `process.env`. Your solution with the `--no-override` flag is correct. On top of that, the line above worked directly from the terminal.